# All In One Seo Pack (AIOSP). Получить сео кастомной записи с другого блога

Tags: wordpress, seo, redirect, wp-plugin, wp-query

На днях столкнулся с задачей вывода постов с одного блога в другом.
Вывод настроил путем настроек постоянных ссылок.

У меня есть заригистрированный кастомный тип. Записи этого типа выводятся через single.php. Проверяя query_vars при необходимсти происходит свитч к нужному блогу для вытягивания записи.

Urls

site.com/quests/post_name ----> вывод поста на текущем блоге (работает замечательно все);
site.com/external/4/post_name2 ---> вывод поста с другого блога на текущем блоге
(пост выводится, но со статусом страницы 404), где "4" => id блога

Вид url на блоге с id 4
site.com/site-name/quests/post_name2

Все метаданные удается получить без проблем этим способом. Но есть ряд проблем:

1. В загаловках передается 404 status. Меняю статус на 200 при существовании на другом блоге и отсутсвующего на текущем блоге поста.
2. AIOSEOPack не работатет для этой записи. Берутся данные для 404 статуса.

Есть идеи как я могу заставить это работать правильно?

```
register_post_type( 'quest',
            array(
                'menu_icon'=>'dashicons-tickets-alt',
                'labels' => array(
                    'name' => __('Quest', 'questhunter'),
                    'singular_name' => __( 'Quest', 'questhunter'),
                    'add_new' => __('Add new quest', 'questhunter'),
                    'menu_name' => __( 'Quests', 'questhunter')
                ),
                'supports'=> array('title','editor','thumbnail','page-attributes','comments'),
                'public' => true,
                'publicly_queryable' => true,
                'hierarchical' => false,
                'taxonomies' => array( 'category' ),
                'has_archive' => true,
                'rewrite' => array(
                    'slug' => 'quests'
                ),
            )
        );
```

Правила и редирект

```
function custom_add_rewrite_rules() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    add_rewrite_tag('%from_blog_id%','([^&]+)');
//    add_rewrite_tag('%external%','([^&]+)');

    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^external/([0-9]+)/([a-z-]+)[/]?$',
        'index.php?post_type=quest&from_blog_id=$matches[1]&name=$matches[2]',
        'top'
    );
//    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'external', EP_PERMALINK | EP_PAGES );

    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}
add_action('init', 'custom_add_rewrite_rules');

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'unlisted_jobs_redirect' );
function unlisted_jobs_redirect($template)
{
    // check if is a 404 error, and it's on your jobs custom post type
    if( is_404())
    {
        $blog_id = get_query_var('from_blog_id');
        $postname = get_query_var('name');

        if ($blog_id) {
            switch_to_blog($blog_id);
            global $wp_query, $post;
            $new_wp_query = new WP_Query(
                array(
                    'post_type' => 'quest',
                    'name' => $postname,
                    'from_blog_id' => $blog_id,
                    'quest' => $postname
                ));
            if (!empty($new_wp_query->posts)) {
                $wp_query = $new_wp_query;
                header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
            }
            restore_current_blog();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. чтоб 404 не было - нужно еще отфильтровать главный запрос

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_modify_main_query'); 

function my_modify_main_query( $query ) {
        
            if ( $query->is_main_query()) { 
                
                    // отработать параметры
            
                    //unset($query->query_vars['p']);
                    
                    //unset($query->query_vars['name']);
                    
                    //unset($query->query_vars['pagename']);
                    
                    //unset($query->query_vars['attachment']);
            }
}
```

2. для SEO использовать соответствующие фильтры

https://semperplugins.com/documentation/aioseop_title/

```
add_filter( 'aioseop_title', 'change_wordpress_seo_title' );

function change_wordpress_seo_title( $title ){
    $title = 'modified title';
    return $title;
}
```

http://hookr.io/filters/aioseop_description_full/

```
function my_aioseo_paged_desc($description) {
        return $description;
}
add_filter( 'aioseop_description_full', 'my_aioseo_paged_desc');
```

http://hookr.io/plugins/all-in-one-seo-pack/2.3.9.2/filters/aioseop_keywords/

```
function fn_keywords($text) {
    return "keywords, keywords!";
}
             
add_filter('aioseop_keywords', 'fn_keywords');
```

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю вас... А если точнее зачем pre_get_posts? Я получаю нужную мне запись, и главеый запрос я подменяю полностью (знаю грубо) на очередь другого блога. У меня не стоит проблема  с выводом записи с другого блога. Стоит проблема вывода мета данных с другого блога для записи с другого блога. А хуки это интересно, да я пробовал, да и продолжал бы пробовать если бы не мета 404 страницы. Даже не метаданные записи, а метаданные с aiseop плагина

Comment: нужно переделать. неправильно под 404 при подключение шаблона ссылаться. когда идет 'template_redirect' уже мета сформированы. нужно на этапе обработки main_query  ('pre_get_posts')- подстроить, чтоб главный цикл выбрал какую-то техническую страницу и уже по активной технической странице - делать переопределение содержимого, переопределение меты

Comment: уже близко. В pre_get_posts я запихнул нужную мне таблицу в очередь ($wpdb->posts) и все сео отдаются как нужно (очень странно что даже очень как нужно вывелись сео для нужного мне блога с названием и описанием постов с другого блога), но столкнулся с другой проблемой... В хидере грузятся данные с текущего блога... И тут для меня наступает момент неописумой магии... Когда пользователь авторизован, инфа о категориях и других страницах отображается как надо... Когда пользователь не авторизован - инфа в хидере просто отсутсвует... Есть идеи?

Comment: смотреть главный запрос под пользователем и гостем. возможно, кеширование

Comment: точно не кэш, $wp_query одинаковые, что под гостем что под пользователем... В общем и на этом спасибо буду продолжатть ковырять

Answer (score 0):

В общем проблему я решил с 404 страницей. Я убрал хук на template_redirect и использовал вместо него pre_get_posts. Получилось следующее:

```
function my_modify_main_query( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_main_query()) {
        global $wpdb;
        $blog_id = $query->query_vars['from_blog_id'];
        if (!empty($blog_id)) {
            if ($blog_id == 1) {
                $wpdb->posts = "wp_posts";
            } else {
                $wpdb->posts = "wp_{$blog_id}_posts";
            }

        }
    }
}
```

В итоге все сеоданные берутся дефолтные... Заполнененные поля для сео (на оригинальном посте) не отображаются для этого поста на неродном блоге (отображаются сего для незоплненных полей). Обратился в тех поддержку и жду ответов. Т.к. это проблема запутанного плагина.

Как итог:

1. Вопрос с 404 страницей решен полностью
2. Вопрос с корректным отображением сео данных буду решать в техподдрежке плагина